# Get offsetTop & IE

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the offsetTop in IE but this simply doesn't work like I want to it.

```
                var miniMap = $('#miniMap'),
                    parnts = miniMap.parents(),
                    l = parnts.length,
                    i, setVpos,
                    setHPos = $('#showMap').position().left;

                for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
                    if (parnts[i].className === 'smallBox') {
                        if (isIE) {
                            setVpos = parnts[i].offsetTop; // returns the wrong value
                        }
                        else {
                            setVpos = parnts[i].offsetTop; // works as it should
                        }
                    }
                }
```

As you can see I am using jQuery. I could of course use the jQuery offset/position().top && .each:

```
       parnts.each(function() {
            if ($(this).hasClass('smallBox')) {
                setVpos = $(this).position().top;
            } ....
```

.. BUT, I've heard ".each" is much slower than using a for loop. Also I am really curious and would love to know what you guys used before jQuery :-)

My problem is when doing it with a for loop I can't use the jQuery obj => position().left won't work.

I've Googled and found the following:

```
document.getElementById("elementID").offsetLeft // all other
document.all.elementID.offsetLeft // IE only
```

I figured perhaps this could work:

```
if (isIE) {
   setVpos = document.all.parnts[i].offsetTop;
}
```

.. but it didn't. So now I'm asking you guys for help instead.

Any suggestion? Thanks on beforehand!

Comment: The performance difference between `each(...)` and `for` is negligible compared to things that can really impede your performance. As Donald Knuth said: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You clearly have a reference to the jQuery library, so why aren't you using it to get the offset?  Using jQuery, you should have no need for any variables such as `isIE`.  The biggest benefit of using a library is cross-browser compatibility.  Here's how you could do it...

```
var off = $(parnts[i]).offset();
alert(off.top);
```

[offset on jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Comment: because a for loop is faster than .each
- like i said in my text.

and with a for loop i can't use $(this).offset().top but instead have to use 
parnts[i].offsetTop which returns the wrong value in IE

Comment: @meow That's not a valid reason.  I doubt your loop is faster.  Regardless, you dont need a `this` reference to use jQuery. Try my code and be happy.

Comment: @ josh:
you were totally right! I never knew you could create a jQuery obj like that! Thanks heaps. Here's my solution:

setVpos = $(parnts[i]).position().top;

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that IE gives a very different answer when offset() is used as opposed to other browsers . Perhaps you should try to run you code before you psot an answer.